# How is it possible to give a user a certain update right, but without the possibility to normaly use it?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, admin

So, i made a connection in c# with my mysql database. And i need the users to have access to certain stuff. But i'm afraid, that if i give them an update command, that they can abuse it.
The command should just increase the variable occurrences by 1 if the name occurs more than once. And this should trigger at the beginning, when you enter your Name. Not more.
 How can i give them this certain update right in mysql/c# without the possibily for them to abuse it?
In c# i did it with this command, but only when i was the admin, or when i gave the whole update right to the user.

```cs
var query = "update TPersonen set PerVorkommen = (PerVorkommen + 1) where PerVorname = '" + PerName + "'";
´´´
```

Comment: If you are concerned about abuse, you probably should not be giving users such access.  There should be an admin or someone else where they can make requests.

Comment: Have you considered using a stored procedure to control the exact update that you allow? It's always much safer anyway and avoids potential SQL injections.

Comment: Yes, stored procedures helped me a lot. Thanks!